# Retrieving values from multiple generic types in list [Is this even possible]

Tags: c#, generics

Consider this scenario.

```
    public abstract class DocumentBase
    {
        public int Index { get; set; }
    }

    public class Document<T> : DocumentBase where T : class
    {
        //Items which are to be inserted into a table on the document
        private List<T> TableItems;

        public Document(int index, List<T> tableItems)
        {
            Index = index;
            TableItems = tableItems; 
        }
    }
```

I then create a list of DocumentBase, but fill the list with types of 'Document' with the generic being different in each item.

```
        var documents = new List<DocumentBase>();

        var documentContentsType1 = new List<DocumentContentType1> { new DocumentContentType1("docInfo1") };
        var documentContentsType2 = new List<DocumentContentType2> { new DocumentContentType2("docInfo2") };

        var documentType1 = new Document<DocumentContentType1>(1, documentContentsType1);
        var documentType2 = new Document<DocumentContentType2>(2, documentContentsType2);

        documents.Add(documentType1);
        documents.Add(documentType2);
```

So I have added two different document types to the documentbase list.

I now want to access properties from Document class of each list. So like this for example, `documents[0].TableItems`

I can only access properties from DocumentsBase, understandably.

What can I change in my setup to fix this?

Comment: You're trying to access a property from a derived class. This will not work, since the actual class of documents[0] isn't known at compile time. You could extract the TableItems property into the Baseclass (DocumentBase), if it makes sense in your abstraction.

Comment: I can't do that because the TableItem relies on the generic passed into the Document class.

Comment: What do you need to _do_ with the `TableItems`? You won't know the type at compile time, so what can you do with it?

Comment: I need to write out their values to a document.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare abstract method in `DocumentBase` and then override it in child classes, so it returns some info about object (it'll be kind of getter). I can't think of any other way.

Comment: This wouldn't work because I couldn't convert the TableItems to a dynamic list. It wouldn't be until runtime it would realize it is a list.

Answer (score 0):

There is a probability that some adds an object of a class which inherits from DocumentBase, but is not of type Document.

What you can do is:

```
documents.OfType<Document<DocumentBaseType>>().ToList()[0].TableItems

public abstract class DocumentBaseType{}
```

And make your DocumentType1 and DocumentType2 extend DocumentBaseType

Comment: I'm trying to make it generic so I won't be able to specify the type.